# In unity how to transfer one input field text or label text from one to another class input field text or label text?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

In unity 2019 how we transfer one input field text to another class label or input field text ? i have tried inheritance and make my variables public too. But did't work.

my code isn't showing any error but not transferring values,showing null values error on running.
When i run the Code it's showing NullObjectRefrence error in SessionData Class  UserNameTextLabel.text; and  UserIDTextLabel.text.

```
 public class LogIn : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public InputField  UsernameTXTBOX;
 public InputField PasswrodTXTBOX;
 public TMPro.TMP_Text UserNameTextLabel;
 public TMPro.TMP_Text UserIDTextLabel;
 public int UserID;

 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {

 }
 public void SceneSwitcher(int SceneIndex)
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneIndex);
 }

 public void Verify()
 {
     if (UsernameTXTBOX.text.Equals("Abc") && PasswrodTXTBOX.text.Equals("def"))
     {
         Debug.Log(UsernameTXTBOX.text);
         // Session["Data"] = UserNameIDTXTBOX.Text;
         UserID = 1234;
         SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
     }
     else if (UsernameTXTBOX.text.Equals("Teacher") && PasswrodTXTBOX.text.Equals("1234"))
     {
         Debug.Log(UsernameTXTBOX.text);
         UserID = 1234;
         SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
     }
     else if (UsernameTXTBOX.text.Equals("Def") && PasswrodTXTBOX.text.Equals("0000"))
     {
         SceneManager.LoadScene(3);
     }
     else
     {
        // UnityEditor.EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Warning","Invalid Ceredentials","Close");
     }    } }


public class SessionData : Monobehaviour
{ 
LogIn L = new LogIn();
 public TMPro.TMP_Text UserNameTextLabel;
 public TMPro.TMP_Text UserIDTextLabel;

 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {  
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
    // Debug.Log(UsernameTXTBOX.text);
     UserNameTextLabel.text = UsernameTXTBOX.text;
     UserIDTextLabel.text = UserID.ToString();       
 } }
```

Comment: Are these two different classes? If so how should `SessionData` know the `UserID`? It seems not to have such a member. Could you describe exactly which data you want to pass from where to where?

Comment: Can you divide that code section into multiple section like by separating classes from each other so reader can read and understand your code easily. Also explain relation between the two classes for better understanding.

Comment: Also as @derHugo mentioned you must have object reference for a class from which you want to access data...                   In your case "SessionData" class need above class object reference to access data.

Comment: @derHugo  LogIn L = new LogIn(); i have created a object in SessionData Class But not helping me in transfering One class textbox value to another class label text.

Answer (score 0):

First of all **you can not use `new` on `MonoBehaviour`!**

It also makes no sense. A component is always attached to a `GameObject` and can not exist without one.

---

What you want to do is rather get a reference to an existing instance of `LogIn`.

There are lots of options some of them being e.g. either a simple serialized field in `SessionData`

```
// drag the according object or component here in the Inspector
// or click on the little dot right next to it
// and select one from the pop-up list
public LogIn logIn;
```

or get a reference on runtime. If the component is on the same `GameObject` e.g. using [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html)

```
private void Awake ()
{
    if(!logIn) logIn = GetComponent<LogIn>();
}
```

Or e.g. if there is only one of this type in the scene you can use [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

```
private void Awake ()
{
    if(!logIn) logIn = FindObjectOfType<LogIn>();
}
```

---

Once you have this reference you can access all its `public` fields, methods and properties via the reference like

```
UserIDTextLabel.text = logIn.UserID.ToString();
```

---

I suggest some general c# basics and [Unity beginner tutorials](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/coding-in-unity-for-the-absolute-beginner#5cf19e6dedbc2a38d6e996c2). And reading the manual e.g. [Controlling GameObjects with Components](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html) where all these basics are covered.